# Unpack lua table as object and map them as function arguments

Tags: lua

I'm looking for a way to unpack lua table(**object, not an array**) and map return value as arguments to a function.
Example:

```lua
local function f(a, b, c, d)
    print(a, b, c, d)
end

--order is messed up on purpose
local object_to_unpack = {
    a = 1,
    c = 42,
    d = 18,
    b = 102
}
```

So Im looking for a way to do something like
`f(unpack_and_map(object_to_unpack))` and for function to output `1, 102, 42, 18`.
I know about `unpack` function, but it only works on arrays, not objects, and I don't have any ordering guarantees(as demonstrated in object_to_unpack)

Comment: `order is messed up on purpose` part is irrelevant, it's always "messed up" in the table, you don't have any control over the order of values in a hash table

Comment: Yea I know that, doesn't hurt to be there

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to unpack that table and not just use it as the functions parameter.

```
local someTable = {
  a = 1,
  c = 42,
  d = 18,
  b = 102,
}

local function f(t)
  print(t.a, t.b, t.c, t.d)
end

f(someTable)
```

If you insist on calling `f` with a list of expressions you need to create one.

```
function f(...)
  print(...)
end

local args = {}
for _, v in pairs(someTable) do
  table.insert(args, v)
end

f(table.unpack(args))
```

This does not guarantee any order. If you want the list ordered by the keys you need to sort that list prior to calling `f`.

```
local keys = {}
for k in pairs(someTable) do
  table.insert(keys, k)
end
table.sort(keys)
local args = {}
for _, key in ipairs(keys) do
  table.insert(args, someTable[key])
end

f(table.unpack(args))
```

Comment: `Not sure why you want to unpack that table and not just use it as the functions parameter` Im doing that now, but i am doing this in a case where I have multiple functions with different arguments which i call from the same place(something like `local fn = get_function_by_some_condition(condition) fn(args) ` So I have to write many functions which extract those arguments from table, which is not that bad, but this would be much better.

Comment: feeding function arguments in alphabetical order is very unusual and error prone. I wouldn't recommend doing that. a single nil value is enough to cause a mismatch.